# PHP: Regarding the view layer in MVC?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

Regarding the MVC pattern, the view layer is supposed to be the functions that 'return' HTML data, or the view layer is actually the HTML data itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View classes in MVC-inspired patterns for web (it is extremely hard to implement classical MVC on web, and impossible with only PHP) are responsible for presentation logic. Then create response to requests and juggle multiple templates.

The way how information gets from model layer to the chosen view largely depends on which of MVC-inspired patterns is implemented. If you are using MVP or MVVM, then information is provided by the controller and the view is passive ( but view is **not a dumb template**). If you are going with Model2 MVC or HMVC patterns, then view is active an requests information from model layer.

When this view has acquired the information , it decides with templates to combine. Or even if templates are even necessary. And then create the response.

The response that each View generated can be HTML, JSON, XML or just plain text. Or, if it's required, sent only a HTTP header (like when doing redirect). This all is part of presentation logic.

Answer (score 3):

The borderline of model, controller and view can be shown this way:

```
/* model models/post.php */

<?php
  class Post {
    public static all() {
      return Array(...);
    }
  }
?>

/* controller /posts/index.php */

<?php
  require "../../models/post.php"
  $posts = Post.all();
  require "../../views/posts/index.php"
?>

/* view /views/posts/index.php */

<?php foreeach ($posts as $post): ?>
  <p><?php echo $post['name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*Ideologically it may be just function but common practice is something like template in template engines. So view layer is `html + data insertions` (without logic of how we get and why). Again ideologically it is function too, but not function of programming language of framework, for example.*

Comment: It is very simplified and erroneous look at MVC (it is actually the same misimplementation of MVP, that has been spread by Rails). Your answer insists, that there is no logic in the views. Basically your answer is same as [pckabeer's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11707811/727208), only with padding of bad code.

Answer (score 0):

View is the "template"
Model is the "Data"
Controller is the "connector" and the algorithems places.

Comment: -1 : view is not a template, model is not data and you don't even have the slightest idea what controller is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

View Layer is subjected to what you want to be visible on client as a presentation. In most cases it is HTML, CSS and Javascript you can also use XML and JSON.

In genral,

Controller ask Model to provide Data.

Controller can than make changes to this data as it need.

Controller send data to View to present with help of template/html.

Comment: That's the bastardization of MVP, popularized by Rails and other prototyping-focused frameworks.

Comment: No I am talking about MVC not MVP

Comment: Controller which requests information from model layer and passes it to instance of view is called "presenter".

Answer (score -1):

View Layer is the functions that return the HTML Data

Comment: -1 , view is not a layer. It is part of "presentation layer" which is made up from both views and controllers. Also, since when layers are made up from functions ?

Comment: If OP's both proposed answers are wrong, you obliged to choose one.